# How to call concatenated column in outer query from subquery in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

In my subquery result I have concatenated first_name and last_name. In my outer query I'm calling subquery "temp". Since I have concatenated columns in my subquery, how to call that concatenated column in my outer query?

For example purpose, I have put Employee name within quotes which I know is why it's giving incorrect result by showing "Employee Name" as the 1st column values instead of showing actual employee names.

SQL query:

```
Select "Employee Name", 
       dept_name, Salary, 
       sum(Salary) OVER (partition by dept_name) as "Total Sal Dept", 
       avg(Salary) OVER (partition by dept_name) as "Avg Sal / Dept"
FROM (   
       Select concat(employees.first_name, ", ",employees.last_name) as "Employee Name", 
              departments.dept_name, 
              Max(salaries.salary) as "Salary"
       FROM departments 
       JOIN dept_manager ON (departments.dept_no = dept_manager.dept_no) 
       JOIN salaries ON (dept_manager.emp_no = salaries.emp_no) 
       JOIN employees ON (salaries.emp_no = employees.emp_no)
       Group by employees.first_name, employees.last_name, departments.dept_name
     ) as temp
```

[Subquery temp result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxRtG.png)

[Outer query with subquery temp result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6gK9.png)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! (Remove everything not needed to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: as shown in FlexYourData's answer, the column name is `Employee Name`.  It needs to be quoted in backticks to use it, like other identifiers that contain special characters or are reserved words.  Note that if you remove the `as "Employee Name"` then the column name is `concat(employees.first_name, ", ",employees.last_name)`, which you could then just select (using backticks).  It's easier to just alias to names that don't require quoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use back-ticks instead of double-quotes.

```
select `Employee Name`
from (select 'your, name' AS "Employee Name") temp
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f22afe3620a4fb14e7bf272712832e2)

Better yet, avoid putting spaces in your column names while building your output. If you must have them formatted with spaces, do it at the very end.

```
select employee_name AS "Employee Name"
from (select 'your, name' AS employee_name) temp
```